# StickyNav - debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
// STICKY NAVBAR

var num = 816; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
});
```

Thisis my code for the sticky navbar (using a custom Bootstrap navbar), and It works fantastic on Desktop browsers...but the `var num` is measured in pixels instead of `em`. That doesn't translate well to mobile.

Is there a way to:

- Measure the scroll in `em` instead of `px`
  or...
- Detect when the bar hits the top of the window and then make it stick instead of using hard-coded measurements?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is not related to a different measurement on mobile devices, cause it's always measured and calculated in pixels on any device. It's more likely that the position of your navbar is just different on a mobile device.

And yes, a solution would be to get the current offset of your navbar and use that instead of the hard coded 'num', like so:

```
var navbarOffset = $('.navbar').offset();
var num = navbarOffset.top;
```

But please keep in mind that this approach assumes that the position of the navbar will not change during the its lifetime. Once your dealing with a responsive design you should recalculate the navbar offset every time the size of a content wrapper element changes.
How elaborate this whole thing can get you can check out here:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js